# For convex $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, d is of minumum norm in $\partial f(x)$ if and only if $-d/||d||$ minimizes $f'(x:d)$ over $||d||\leq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Okay, so I am having some problems with convex analysis review before my optimization exam. I want to prove that

For convex $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, d is of minimum norm in $\partial f(x)$ if and only if $-d/||d||$ minimizes $f'(x:d)$ over $\|d\|\leq 1$.

$-d/ \|d\|$ minimizes $f'(x:d)$ s.t $d^t d\leq 1$. So we have
$\nabla f(x) d = \lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{f(x+\alpha d)-f(x)}{\alpha}$ and since $d$ is a subgradient
$$\frac{f(x+\alpha y)-f(x)}{\alpha}\geq y^t d, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n,\alpha >0.$$

But now I am stuck... I think it shouldn't be far now but I am missing something.

Notation: $\partial f(x)$ is the set of subgradients of $f$ at $x$, $f'(x:d)=\nabla f(x)^t d$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ with direction $d$.

Any help, tips or the solution would be well appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Edit: removed differentiability assumption

Edit2:

DF subgradient (S is convex)
$$\partial f(x)=\{d: f(y)\geq f(x)+d(y-x), \forall y \in S\}.$$

Comment: Could you explain your notation a bit?  What does "$d$ is of minimum norm in $\partial f(x)$" mean?  What does $f'(x:d)$ mean? I ask since this seems to be mostly a multivariable calculus question (which many people on this site could answer), but phrased in the language of convex analysis which is perhaps not spoken by as many people.

Comment: $\partial f(x)$ is the set of subgradients of $f$ at $x$, $f'(x:d)=\nabla f(x)^t d$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ with direction $d$. But, I think i made a mistake since differentiability wasn't assumed...